# What does &argv[2] represent?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, argv

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%s\n", mystrtype(argc - 2, &argv[2], argv[1]));
    return (0);
}
```

But I couldn't understand how to represent `&argv[2]` in my head as `argv[2]` already represents the second line of a 2D array. What part of the array is `&argv[2]` pointing to? Thanks.

Comment: is this a working code?

Comment: You are thinking about it on too high a level.  `argv[2]` is a `char *` that *points to* the first character of a `char` array.  `&argv[2]` is the address of that pointer.  The expression is equivalent to `argv + 2`.

Comment: Please show `mystrtype`, indeed a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: Yes, I just use another function called mystrtype whose prototype is char *mystrtype(int size, char **array, char *string)

Comment: `&argv[2]` is of type `char**`, and it's basically a pointer to the 3rd element of `argv` (i.e.: `argv[2]`, which is of type `char*`). `&argv[2]` can be interpreted as an array of `char*` which starts at the 3rd element of `argv`.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit the question to include the *full code*. May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

`argv` is declared as having the type `char **`.

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
```

So the expression `argv[2]` has the type `char *` and the expression `&argv[2]` has the type `char **`. The expression `&argv[2]` can be also rewritten like `argv + 2`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( char **s )
{
    for ( ; *s; ++s ) printf( "%s ", *s );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char * s[] = { "Hello", "World!", NULL };

    f( s );
    f( &s[0] );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World! 
Hello World!
```

These calls of the function `f`

```
f( s );
f( &s[0] );
```

are equivalent. In this call

```
f( s );
```

the array designator is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

To make it mode clear then if you have for example an array of integers

```
int a[10];
```

then used as a function argument it is converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int *`.

If you have an array of pointers to integers like

```
int * a[10];
```

then used as a function argument it is again converted to pointer of its first element. As the array elements have the type `int *` then the pointer to the first element of the array will have the type `int **`.